# A song in Boku no Hero Academia Season 3 Episode 45 from 10:50 to 11:55

Tags: my-hero-academia

There is a song in Boku no Hero Academia, season 3, episode 45, from 10:50 to 11:55 that doesn't appear anywhere else. Does anyone know the name of that song?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be included in the OST for Boku no Hero Academia 2, track 12: Tsune ni Top wo Nerau Mono (常にトップを狙う者). It seems to use the part starting at around 00:35.